# Why are the fabric peers reporting different network status?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am writing a peer deployment tool that starts fabric peers on different servers: I am starting 4 peers vp0, vp1, vp2, vp3 in a tight loop (via docker client), and for vp1-3, I am setting the environment variable `CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE` to the address of vp0. After all peers are started, I use `GET /network/peers` to get the network status for the cluster, and get the strange results:

```
 For vp0, the peers returned: vp0, vp1, vp2, vp3
 For vp1, the peers returned: vp0, vp1
 For vp2, the peers returned: vp0, vp2
 For vp3, the peers returned: vp0, vp3
```

What is happening here? What should I do to get the correct status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For v0 you can set CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE to all the other nodes, v1,v2,v3. And rootnode will be discovering for all others every time.